# launch Here from my own Android Application

Tags: java, android, mobile, maps, launch

Can I launch "Here" Application from my own Android one to display an itenarary on a map ?

https://developer.here.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need to check the [HERE Docs](https://developer.here.com/documentation), and adding the dependency to your build.gradle file which check all the components that Android is going to use.